# Why UWP cannot find ImageScanner class?

Tags: uwp, scanning

I try to use a flatbed scanner from UWP. Checked [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/scan-from-your-app) and it looked simple and straightforward.

However I certainly miss something because I cannot build (`ImageScanner` is underscored in the editor):

> The type or namespace name 'ImageScanner' cannot be found

Obviously, I have the using `Windows.Devices.Scanners`; in the file. And even that one is weird, because IntelliSense cannot find that namespace but the using line raises no error. I tried with a rubbish namespace and, as expected, with that the using fails.

My project is a new *Windows Universal Blank App*. Haven't changed anything just started to write my class.

> Visual Studio 2017 v4.7.03056
>    Target Platform Version: 10.0.17134.0

Should I change some project properties or app manifest? The only thing I've read that this scanner API works only on desktop UWP and not on mobile. I tried to change the **TargetDeviceFamily** in the `appxmanifest` from `Windows.Universal` to `Windows.Desktop` but did not help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including the exact error message, and an appropriate language tag.

Comment: 1. created new Windows Universal / Blank App

Comment: 1. created new Windows Universal / Blank App  
2. added a class Class1.cs  
3. added using line: using Windows.Devices.Enumeration; - intellisense helped  
4. added using line: using Windows.Devices.Scanners; - intellisense did not help, but no error  
5. wrote a class level field decalration: ImageScanner _scanner; - ImageScanner is red underscored with a tooltip: "The type or namespace name 'ImageScanner' cannot be found..."  
6. tried to build and got the same error: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ImageScanner' could not be found ..

Comment: [Zipped project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkNSXRLoAkOUjY0oRX6nKDkgi0wChw)
[What I See](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkNSXRLoAkOUjY0pYJDOWulAJJpQxw)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you dig into the documentation of [any class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.scanners.iimagescannerformatconfiguration) within this namespace, you will find out that it is in fact defined in the Windows Desktop Extension SDK:

[image: Extension SDK]

This means you have to reference this extension first. Right-click your UWP project in the **Solution Explorer**, select **Add**, **Reference**. In the opened dialog window select **Universal Windows**, **Extensions** on the left-hand side and then find and check appropriate version of the **Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP**. After you confirm the dialog, you should be able to see the members listed in IntelliSense.

[image: Windows Desktop Extension SDK]

Comment: Oh, i thought i missed something basic. Sorry but it wasn't obvious for me since I looked for the assembly in which they are defined. Didn't know that the device family means extra reference. Was a rookie question :(

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :-) . It is something you probably will encounter again while building UWP apps, so it is good to be aware of this trick :-) . Happy coding!